# Salesforce Trigger Field NOT POPULATING - Populate Manager email of Account owner in custom field "Owner Manager Email" on Account

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger PopoulateOwnerManagerEmail on Account (before insert) {

    set<id> ids=new set<id>();
    list<Account> listt =new list<Account>();
    for(Account acc:Trigger.New) {
       ids.add(acc.OwnerId);   
    }

    list<Account> listemail =[
        select Id,
          Name,
          Manager_Email__c,
          Owner.Manager.Email
        from Account
        where Id IN: ids
        ];

    for(Account a : listemail) {
        a.Manager_Email__c = a.Owner.Manager.Email;//custom field Manager_Email__c;
        listt.add(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just make `Manager_Email__c` a formula field?

Comment: That can be a easy way. I wanted to make it difficult one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSmith's answer is close, but not entirely correct.

You're using a `before insert` trigger. Normally, in `before` triggers, you can save yourself a DML operation by directly editing the records in `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.newMap`.

In a `before insert` trigger, only `Trigger.new` is available.

The issue that you're running into is that because it's a `before insert` trigger, the records in `Trigger.new` don't yet have an Id.

This makes your Id set empty (or rather, it will contain a single `null` at the end of the loop), which in turn makes your query return 0 results.

The overall logic is sound, you'll just need to change this to be an `after insert` trigger so your trigger records have Ids. Because it's now an `after` trigger, `Trigger.new` will be read-only, and you'll need to perform a DML update (as TSmith has indicated).

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget to perform your DML once you have gathered the List of Ids that need to be updated.

```
 trigger PopoulateOwnerManagerEmail on Account (before insert) {

        set<id> ids=new set<id>();
        list<Account> listt =new list<Account>();
        for(Account acc:Trigger.New) {
           ids.add(acc.OwnerId);   
        }

        list<Account> listemail =[
            select Id,
              Name,
              Manager_Email__c,
              Owner.Manager.Email
            from Account
            where Id IN: ids
            ];

        for(Account a : listemail) {
            a.Manager_Email__c = a.Owner.Manager.Email;//custom field Manager_Email__c;
            listt.add(a);
        }

        update listt;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah TSmith. But, no need to use DML statements when we are using **before** triggers.

Comment: @SourabhCoolkarni, As pointed out by Derek.